# What does atlOrigin query parameter mean in Jira URL?

Tags: security, web, url, networking, request

When I open a Jira issue link from a third party or copy from a clipboard I always find the URL looks like this:

https://mycompany.atlassian.net/browse/comapnyAlias-issueNumber?atlOrigin=longCharacters

I am curious what does **atlOrigin** means? and why do they use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a small explanation here https://developer.atlassian.com/developer-guide/client-identification/

> Origin ID for links to Atlassian UI
> Identify HTML links into our product user interface with a unique `atlOrigin` [query string parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) added to the URL. This is similar to the UTM parameter used for click tracking in marketing web sites. In this context, uniqueness is guaranteed by Atlassian issuing the origin ID. For example, if linking into Jira’s Issue page:
>
> ```
> https://devpartisan.atlassian.net/browse/TIS-11?atlOrigin=abc123
> ```
>
> We generate a unique value for each integration so if you have more than 1 integration, please make sure we have properly associated each integration to a different origin value.
>
> We do not recommend using this parameter in REST APIs or OAuth 2.0 flows, where this parameter might not be properly ignored.

Result is very Google Search - unfriendly to come up